# Hyper-V Ubuntu 20.04.: Very low LAN cable connection

Tags: lan, connection, hyper-v, ubuntu-20.04

I have installed Ubunti 20.04.1 LTS on Hyper-V.

RAM: 2048 MB
4 virtual processors

My PC is connected via LAN cable and has 30 Mbit/s download.

For my virtual Ubuntu I use the default switch. But inside Ubuntu I only have 20 kbit/s, so that even small downloads take super long.

What can I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party firewall? I'm assuming you're using the `Default` switch, not an external one created in Network Switch Manager? If so, go into your regular ethernet adapter's Properties → Configure... → Advanced and review those settings

Comment: Yes, I use the `Default` switch. On the parent system only Windows Defender Firewall is activated.

Comment: I've never come across such an issue when using Hyper-V; you may need to do some troubleshooting to rule out what the issue is: the VM _(create a new VM and install 20.04 LTS to see if it replicates)_, LAN ethernet adapter advanced settings on Windows _(this seems the most likely to me)_, Hyper-V itself _(remove Hyper-V via `optionalfeatures`, reboot, then re-add it)_, etc.